# Rounding up prices in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm currently coding an ecommerce website that has hundreds of products and I need to round up all the prices, so if one product costs £97.72, it needs to be rounded up to £98. I'm coding in asp.net, and this is the code I have so far, but it's not working. Have I missed something?

```
<%
function roundUp(x)
   If x > Int(x) then
    roundup = Int(x) + 1
   Else
    roundup = x
   End If
End Function
%>
```

Comment: Can you update your question showing how this function is being used on your page?

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in function called [Math.Ceiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=net-5.0) that performs that.

Just beware what "round up" exactly means to you for negative number, but `Ceiling` does the same thing as your code (i.e. -2.3 rounds up to -2).

As for your own code, it's hard to say why it's not working at first glance, esp. since you didn't give examples of what doesn't work.
I suppose if `x` is a `Double` you might be surprised by some rounding errors where you assume `x` is an integer but is actually very slightly above?
Or since you use dynamic typing here (no static type is given to `x`), maybe it's not a number but rather a `String` and that leads to unexpected results?